# Firefox right-click opens context menu, but selects tabs instead

Tags: firefox, bug-reporting, debugging, context-menu, firefox-extensions

At first when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, firefox was working normally. There had been some issues with the on-screen touchboard keyboard opening up when unwanted and so I installed caribou 36 to prevent the keyboard from popping up every time I touched the screen to type something (unsure if related, am just listing the events as they happened).

Later on, not immediately, every time I right click to bring up the context menu on firefox the context menu would pop up (which is normal), but I would put my cursor over it and it would highlight my above tabs instead of highlighting the context menu option.

When I click it's not the context menue that is clicked, but rather the highlight tab above. I haven't a clue what is going on here. I tried reinstalling firefox which solved the issue for a day, but now its back again.

I've looked online everywhere for solutions, but it doesn't seem that anyone has had my problem before.

The laptop I use is the Dell Inspiron 16 7620 2-in-1. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS